# Android app indexing using firebase having no website

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I want to implement App indexing using firebase android Api. But it says there is need to establish association between app and website b generating Digital Asset Link file. But I do not have website for my app.So is it possible to implement App Indexing without website? If yes how to create [Android app deep links](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3)

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a website to do this.

However, there's no requirement that *you* have to host it. [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) helps take care of this by hosting placeholder pages for each piece of content you want to have indexed.

[Read here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-google-app-indexing-with-deep-links/) for more info on how to set it up.

Comment: Hello. Is it still possible to Index an App without a webpage?